# Find duplicate records in MySQL for each customer ID

Tags: mysql, sql, having

i try to find duplicate records for each customer.

Table: customers_points

```
points_id + customers_id + points_comment 
    1           200          From Order: 5227 
    2           200          From Order: 5227 
    3           200          From Order: 5227 
    4           201          From Order: 7000 
    5           201          From Order: 7000 
    6           202          From Order: 6000 
    7           203          From Order: 8000
```

the result should be like this:

```
customers_id  + duplicate_rows
    200              3
    201              2
```

below is my current sql query(not accurate):

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM  `customers_points` c
INNER join (SELECT points_comment FROM `customers_points` GROUP BY points_comment HAVING count(customers_id) > 1) dup 
ON c.points_comment = dup.points_comment
WHERE c.points_date_added > '2014-04-01 12:01:00'
GROUP BY c.customers_id
ORDER BY c.points_date_added DESC limit 100
```

Comment: Just run your inner query by itself.

Comment: check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/071ad/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT customers_id, count(points_comment) duplicate_rows
FROM customers_points
GROUP BY customers_id, points_comment`